How do I tabulate the last 2 production defect info. based on date of manufacturing per location, per product and per defect?
There are two production units, one in the US and one in Australia. The US plant produces Food and Drinks while the Australian plant produces Food and Stationeries. I have a table that consists of the product ID, date of manufacturing of the products, defects in the products and the cost of defects in USD for each of these defects. The table is as shown below.



Product ID
Location
Product
Date of manufacturing
Defect
Cost of Defect in USD




USF01
US
Food
04/13/2024
Expired
29


USF52
US
Food
04/20/2024
Expired
26


USF08
US
Food
04/12/2024
Expired
94


USF22
US
Food
04/14/2024
Expired
73


USF11
US
Food
04/10/2024
Packing error
25


USF08
US
Food
04/12/2024
Packing error
82


USF99
US
Food
04/19/2024
Packing error
82


USF52
US
Food
04/20/2024
Packing error
32


USD07
US
Drinks
04/12/2024
Expired
7


USD53
US
Drinks
04/14/2024
Expired
81


USD38
US
Drinks
04/20/2024
Expired
16


USD76
US
Drinks
04/13/2024
Expired
55


USD76
US
Drinks
04/13/2024
Packing error
79


USD07
US
Drinks
04/12/2024
Packing error
55


USD99
US
Drinks
04/15/2024
Packing error
14


USD29
US
Drinks
04/17/2024
Packing error
7


AUS51
Australia
Stationery
04/19/2024
Expired
33


AUS12
Australia
Stationery
04/13/2024
Expired
56


AUS52
Australia
Stationery
04/08/2024
Expired
15


AUS72
Australia
Stationery
04/20/2024
Expired
15


AUS30
Australia
Stationery
04/09/2024
Packing error
61


AUS72
Australia
Stationery
04/20/2024
Packing error
78


AUS52
Australia
Stationery
04/08/2024
Packing error
22


AUS58
Australia
Stationery
04/12/2024
Packing error
84


AUF58
Australia
Food
04/19/2024
Expired
44


AUF79
Australia
Food
04/18/2024
Expired
10


AUF45
Australia
Food
04/08/2024
Expired
31


AUF88
Australia
Food
04/12/2024
Expired
71


AUF50
Australia
Food
04/08/2024
Packing error
63


AUF88
Australia
Food
04/12/2024
Packing error
27


AUF32
Australia
Food
04/21/2024
Packing error
69


AUF66
Australia
Food
04/19/2024
Packing error
26



I am looking to create a new table which will show the latest 2 rows per location per product and per defect based on the date of manufacturing. The output table should like something like this.



Product ID
Location
Product
Date of manufacturing
Defect
Cost of Defect in USD




USF52
US
Food
04/20/2024
Expired
26


USF22
US
Food
04/14/2024
Expired
73


USF52
US
Food
04/20/2024
Packing error
32


USF99
US
Food
04/19/2024
Packing error
82


USD38
US
Drinks
04/20/2024
Expired
16


USD53
US
Drinks
04/14/2024
Expired
81


USD29
US
Drinks
04/17/2024
Packing error
7


USD99
US
Drinks
04/15/2024
Packing error
14


AUF58
Australia
Food
04/19/2024
Expired
44


AUF79
Australia
Food
04/18/2024
Expired
10


AUF32
Australia
Food
04/21/2024
Packing error
69


AUF66
Australia
Food
04/19/2024
Packing error
26


AUS72
Australia
Stationery
04/20/2024
Expired
15


AUS51
Australia
Stationery
04/19/2024
Expired
33


AUS72
Australia
Stationery
04/20/2024
Packing error
78


AUS58
Australia
Stationery
04/12/2024
Packing error
84



Also, I'm trying to obtain a visual where I can see the consolidated defect costs for the latest 2 rows per location per product and per defect based on the date of manufacturing. The output will be as such.



Location
Product
Defect
Cost of Defect in USD




US
Food
Expired
99


US
Drinks
Expired
97


US
Food
Packing Error
114


US
Drinks
Packing Error
21


Australia
Food
Expired
54


Australia
Stationery
Expired
48


Australia
Food
Packing Error
95


Australia
Stationery
Packing Error
162



I tried using the topn formula but I can't seem to get the right answer at all.

I am diving your question in 2 part :
1st part : create a new table which will show the latest 2 rows per location per product and per defect based on the date of manufacturing
You need to calculate the rank in your main table using a calculated column :
Rank = 
RANKX(
  FILTER(
    ALL('Manufacturers Table'),
    'Manufacturers Table'[Location] = EARLIER('Manufacturers Table'[Location])
    && 'Manufacturers Table'[Product] = EARLIER('Manufacturers Table'[Product])
    && 'Manufacturers Table'[Defect] = EARLIER('Manufacturers Table'[Defect])
  ),
  'Manufacturers Table'[Date of manufacturing],
  ,
  DESC,
  Dense
)

Then create a calculated table where you mention the rank as condition to filter :
LatestDefects = 
CALCULATETABLE(
  'Manufacturers Table',
  FILTER(
    'Manufacturers Table',
    'Manufacturers Table'[Rank] <= 2
  )
)


2nd part : Obtain a visual where I can see the consolidated defect costs for the latest 2 rows per location per product and per defect based on the date of manufacturing
In the calculated table, create the measure :
Sum of Top 2 Defect Costs = 
CALCULATE(
  SUM('YourRankedTableName'[Cost of Defect in USD]),
  'YourRankedTableName'[Rank] <= 2
)



Thanks a lot Amira.. This sure helps.. :-)
